# Matlab audioread doubles instead of singles

Tags: matlab, audio, reshape, sampling

I have the following code at the moment:

```
[y,fs] = audioread('some_audio_file.wav');
```

y is a `<8131546 x 2 double>`. Why is that? How come the samples are not a `1 x 8131546`?

Also when I reshape y to get columns of 30 milliseconds I get a `<1324 x 6146 double>`? Can someone explain why the doubles?

Comment: Have you read the very clear documentation on [`audioread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html) (or `help audioread` or `doc audioread`)? I'm not sure what your question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html#outputarg_y) on `audioread`, the output `y` is:

> Audio data in the file, returned as an m-by-n matrix, where m is the
>   number of audio samples read and n is the number of audio channels in
>   the file.

Therefore it looks like your file has 2 audio channels.

As for what you call "doubles", they are the default format in which MATLAB stores data. Read [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data-types_data-types.html):

> By default, MATLAB® stores all numeric variables as double-precision
>   floating-point values